# postgres plpy.execute with hstore string literal FAIL

Tags: python, postgresql, escaping, plpython

I'm writing a plpython function using postgresql 9.2.  Assume the code has already executed a query that returns hstore strings.   I wish to then issue a query:

```
SELECT hstore_to_matrix('hstorestring')
```

Let's say that it is a string containing the hstore string: `A=>B`

```
create or replace function testfreq() 
returns text
as $$
hstorestring = '"GT"=>"thing","HS"=>"[-0.1,-0.2]"'
rv2 = plpy.execute("SELECT hstore_to_matrix(%s)" % (plpy.quote_literal(hstorestring)))
plpy.log("Hstore:",rv2[0])
return("done")
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Run as

```
select testfreq();
```

Returns

```
testdb=# select testfreq();
ERROR:  plpy.Error: unrecognized error in PLy_spi_execute_fetch_result
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
PL/Python function "testfreq", line 3, in <module>
rv2 = plpy.execute("SELECT hstore_to_matrix(%s)" % (plpy.quote_literal(hstorestring)))
PL/Python function "testfreq":
```

If you replace with hstore_to_array in the code above, the output is:

```
testdb=# select testfreq();
LOG:  ('Hstore:', {'hstore_to_array': ['GT', 'thing', 'HS', '[-0.1,-0.2]']})
CONTEXT:  PL/Python function "testfreq"
testfreq 
----------
done
(1 row)
```

I have also tried to use hstore operators instead of functions and I have tried out these functions in a pgsql terminal to make sure they work when not embedded in python.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The string literal may be a red herring.   I get the same error with any "SELECT yourdbfunc()" query string.

Comment: Another update.  I can execute plpy.execute("SELECT hstore_to_array(%s)" % (ploy.quote_literal(s))).    But not hstore_to_matrix.   Yay for bustedness.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a *complete* example of a function that demonstrates the problem, from `CREATE FUNCTION` onwards. I'd also like to see your Python version if possible. Comment here when done so I get notified please.

Comment: Added complete function that causes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like PL/Python doesn't correctly handle multi-dimensional arrays:

```
create or replace function testarray()
returns text
as $$
rv2 = plpy.execute("SELECT ARRAY[ ARRAY['1','2','3'], ARRAY['a','b','c'] ];" )
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Result:

```
craig=# select testarray();
ERROR:  plpy.Error: unrecognized error in PLy_spi_execute_fetch_result
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "testarray", line 2, in <module>
    rv2 = plpy.execute("SELECT ARRAY[ ARRAY['1','2','3'], ARRAY['a','b','c'] ];" )
PL/Python function "testarray"
```

(Tested on Pg 9.2.4, Python 2.7.3).

The hstore text is valid:

```
craig=# SELECT '"GT"=>"thing","HS"=>"[-0.1,-0.2]"'::hstore;
               hstore               
------------------------------------
 "GT"=>"thing", "HS"=>"[-0.1,-0.2]"
(1 row)
```

and the query works outside PL/Python:

```
craig=# select hstore_to_matrix('"GT"=>"thing","HS"=>"[-0.1,-0.2]"');
        hstore_to_matrix         
---------------------------------
 {{GT,thing},{HS,"[-0.1,-0.2]"}}
(1 row)
```

further suggesting that this is a PL/Python issue.

You can probably work around this by casting to `text` then casting back to `text[]` after returning the result, though it's inefficient:

```
create or replace function testfreq() 
returns text
as $$
hstorestring = '"GT"=>"thing","HS"=>"[-0.1,-0.2]"'
rv2 = plpy.execute("SELECT hstore_to_matrix(%s)::text" % (plpy.quote_literal(hstorestring)))
plpy.log("Hstore:",rv2[0])                                                                                                                                                     
return("done")                                                                                                                                                                 
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Result:

```
craig=# SELECT testfreq();
 testfreq 
----------
 done
(1 row)
```